# Installing SmartWizard in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, themes, yarnpkg, smart-wizard, gentelella

I was implementing [Gentelella Admin Theme](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) in my Rails 5 application. There's already a sample Gentelella Rails 5 app mentioned in their readme but it doesnt have SmartWizard yet. However, the original theme has it already embedded into it. I still want to use it but im unable to do so. Here's what i tried out yet:

1. Installed *smartwizard* from npm repositories using YARN.
2. Updated my application.js and application.scss
3. Added node_modules to assets path in assets.rb

This is what i ended up having(cropped image):
[image]

However, what i want is [here](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form_wizards.html)

Using Rails 5.0.4

Answer (score 0):

you need to init the wizard

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#YOUR_WIZARD_BLOCK_ID').smartWizard();
})
```